# Remember Me - Fetch UserName - MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, remember-me

I am working on ASP.NET MVC5 application and I want to implement RememberMe functionality. Here, when the user check RememberMe then, the username should be automatically fetch to username field, whenever the user go to the website again. I have tried with following methods. But it has problem with it and i am not able to done this. Can anyone help me to do this?

```
var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                                           1,
                                           userId,  //user id
                                           DateTime.Now,
                                           DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(50),  // expiry
                                           model.RememberMe,  //true to remember
                                           string.Empty
                                         );

HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
if (authTicket.IsPersistent)
{
    cookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;
}
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by using following code.
In Controller:
In Login POST action:

```
if(model.RememberMe == true)
                    {
                        Response.Cookies["email"].Value = model.Email;
                        Response.Cookies["email"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
                    }
```

In Login Initial Action:

```
if (Request.Cookies["email"] != null)
                ViewBag.email = Request.Cookies["email"].Value;
```

In View:

```
@if (ViewBag.email != null)
    {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @Value = ViewBag.email })
    }
    else
    {
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    }
```